# Run 1st macro every hour at 14,17,44,47 min and 2nd macro 22,52 min

Tags: excel, vba

Here i have my terrible code, the problem also is 25% Cpu usage when it runs and waits..

```
    Public StopRunning As Boolean
Sub somebutton_click()
    StopRunning = True
End Sub
Sub AutoOn()

  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:14:00"))
  Call Wholeshort
  Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:03:00"))
  Call Wholeshort
  Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:05:00"))
  Call Whole
  Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:22:00"))
  Call Wholeshort
  Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:03:00"))
  Call Wholeshort
  Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:05:00"))
  Call Whole
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True

  If Not StopRunning Then Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:08:00"), "AutoOn"

End Sub
```

i would like to run Macro1 every hour at xx:14,xx:17,xx:44,xx:47 minutes and Macro2 every hour at xx:22,xx:52 minutes and somehow to stop that sub by button. So when i start sub at 14:55, it will start to run 15:14,15:17,15:22 .... infinetly but can be stopped by button (how do i assign a button shortcut to stop like ctrl+x)

Is there a more efficient way to code this, and that i can start this any time, not adjust waiting minutes every time depending when i start this, i need to run this same times every hour as i wrote..

Thank you!

Comment: Don't use `Application.Wait`. Use `Application.OnTime` in each consecutive subs, to call the next one...

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way to run every hour at XX h 14 min better yet?

Comment: Yes! I will post an answer to better explain the logic...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this approach, please:

1. Create two variables at module level (on top of it, in the declarations area):

```
    Private StopRunning as boolean, wCount as long
```

2. All cycle can be start from the `Workbook_Open()` event, or from any other Sub:

```
    Private Sub Workbook_Open()
       Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:14:00"), "Wholeshort"
    End Sub
```

3. Then, in the module with declarations described at item 1, the next two sets of code lines must append your existing subs with their specific names:

```
    Private Sub Wholeshort()
      'existing procedure code...
      '....
      wCount = wCount + 1
      If Not StopRunning Then
        If wCount Mod 2 = 0 Then
            'second time (even) it calls Whole:
            Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:02:00"), "Whole"
            wCount = 0
        Else
            'first time (odd) it calls itself
            Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:03:00"), "Wholeshort"
        End If
      End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub Whole()
      'existing procedure code...
      '....
      If Not StopRunning Then Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:22:00"), "Wholeshort"
    End Sub
```

In order to stop the next `OnTime` call, you can use your procedure:

```
Sub somebutton_click()
    StopRunning = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, ambiguous name detected : wholeshort ... because my macro names are whole and wholeshort they were changed to module2.whole to separate from this module 4.... code doesnt run past 2. part

Comment: @Moment Hood: Such an error is normal, if you have two procedures with the same name... I thought that **you will only append your existing procedures**. If you used a different module, in order to avoid the error, you must declare the procedures in discussion as `Private` (as I did in my adapted code). But **you must make `Private` the existing ones, too**.  Even if they exist in another module...

Comment: I put Private Sub for both macros and in your code there is private sub in front too.... still displays ambiguous error

Comment: @Moment Hood: I edited the code after your complain about the 'ambiguous error'... But, when such an error appear it **must** select the code portion which also exists in another place. What string does it select? If one of the involved subs, press `Ctrl + F` , select 'Current Project' and see where you have a double (maybe triple) exposure. Make all of them Private, or change their names adding something ("__") at their name ending...

Comment: Before   Private Sub Workbook_Open()
       Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:14:00"), "Wholeshort"
    End Sub would run i would get ambiguous error .... why are your code subs and my macros the same name? I have my 2 macros only in VBA project modules , no personal workbook

Comment: @Moment Hood: Do you know what is `Workbook_Open()` event? This must exist in `ThisWokbook` module! Did you, or an add-in use this event (Workbook_Open())? Even Yes, comment all your event code in module, go in `ThisWorkbook` module and add the code line after the existing code. Check to not be a condition and because of that, the code to not reach the end...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216561/discussion-between-moment-hood-and-faneduru).